# how to pass url in java script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

java script functionality working fine on my local system but not on server. my actual jquery code is

```
$('.jeditableSalePrice').editable('/Product/DTUpdateProduct', {
            id: 'SalePrice_ID',
            name: 'value',
            indicator: 'Updating...',
            tooltip: 'Click to Change'
        });
```

now I try by two techniques. both are working on my local but not on server 
1: using @Url.Action("DTUpdateProduct", "Product")'
2: using @Url.Content("/Product/DTUpdateProduct")

```
  //$('.jeditableSalePrice').editable('@Url.Content("/Product/DTUpdateProduct")', {
  $('.jeditablePartNumber').editable('@Url.Action("DTUpdateProduct", "Product")', {
            id: 'SalePrice_ID',
            name: 'value',
            indicator: 'Updating...',
            tooltip: 'Click to Change'
        });
```

any solution to resolve this issue on server ?

Comment: What errors do you get on your server or in your console?

Comment: Is this script in a separate javascript file or is it inline inside your view?

Comment: Jeroen Moons. i am getting no error on server. my fuctionality is not working on their.i actually update grid column value by this function

Comment: Darin Dimitron: this is inline code in my view

Comment: `@Url.Action("DTUpdateProduct", "Product")` should work fine. I guess the issue is somewhere else in your code. Have you debugged your code with FireBug? Are there some errors? Is the controller action being invoked?

Comment: Darin Dimitrov: this functionality is working fine on my local but not on production server. I receive many errors on production environment because on url. all are removed by @url.action . but this is not working with that. any other solution for passing url.